# Execute Command with xterm and close

Tags: linux, bash, shell, xterm

Im trying to execute a program with xterm and then close xterm with program running but it seems this doesn't work like I would expect it.

In bash there is the option `bash -c [command]` is there something in xterm too?
Currently im using `xterm -e [command]` but this keeps the xterm window open till' my program has finished. But I want to open it, run the program, close it and keep the program running.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Why would you like to launch a command through `xterm` if you're not going to use the terminal interractively ?

Comment: Im doing this through xpra on different workstation and this program only works correctly if it is called with the right environment.

Comment: Try `nohup`, `disown`, or GNU `screen` to keep a program running even if its parent process (in this case xterm) is closed.

Comment: Im bound to xpra, how do i use nohub, disown or screen?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I do it (from a bash file) like:

```
my@self:~$ cat /usr/bin/rdesk.sh

#!/bin/bash
xterm -e 'perl /home/my/script.pl'
```

when i run the rdesk.sh file it starts xterm with a perl script, giving me some options. after choosing one, I can close the window, running the chosen program.

So you might just have to put your `xterm -e ...` command into a bash script.